# Why is my function returning undefined despite printing out correctly

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await

### The code

##### the function returning

```
  async getData(key, setHook) {
    try {
      await AsyncStorage.getItem(key).then((response) => {
        console.log("getData response: " + response); // prints out correctly
        setHook(response); // sets my hook as undefined?
      })
    } catch(e) {
      console.log("AsyncStorage getData: error: " + e);
    }
  }
```

##### the function receiving

```
const key = 'key';

const Home = ( {navigation} ) =>  {
  ...
  const [totalBreaks, setTotalBreaks] = useState('0'); // the hook I use in the above function

 // on mount setCounter
 useEffect(() => {  
      setCounter();
 }, []);


 async function setCounter () {
    await asyncStorageInterface.getData(key, setTotalBreaks);
    console.log("total breaks: " + totalBreaks); // returns undefined on mount... when it shouldn't
    if(totalBreaks === null || totalBreaks === undefined) {
      await asyncStorageInterface.storeData(key, '0');
      await asyncStorageInterface.getData(key, setTotalBreaks);
    }
    console.log("total breaks: " + totalBreaks);
  }
```

### Problem

I have no idea what the problem is... I spent almost 6 hours trying to fix this, can someone please help me out? And please explain what the problem is in depth if that's possible so that I can document it somewhere. Thanks.

Comment: Note: using `then` with `await` is an anti-pattern.

Comment: Please provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Try this: `const result = await AsyncStorage.getItem(key); setHook(result);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your `totalBreaks` was read before you set it. it's as simple as:

```
const result = {};
const {val} = result;
result.val = 'foo';
console.log(val); // you will still get undefined.
```

This is not related to asynchronous